# Limits of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$a_n= \frac{10^{6n}}{n!}$$

Show that, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$$

I'm not sure where exactly to start of with this question. Do i show its a decreasing function and then work out $\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ or is it something compleely different?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take any $a>1$. Then $a<\left\lfloor a\right\rfloor+1=k \in \mathbb{N}$. So
$$\frac{a^n}{n!}= \frac{a^k a^{n-k}}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots k \cdot (k+1)  \cdots   n} \leqslant \frac{a^k}{k!} \left(\frac{a}{k+1}\right)^{n-k} \to 0, n\to \infty$$
In your case $a=10^6$